# In the ToC (titletoc), how to make sure the dotted line is never wrongly suppressed?

Tags: table-of-contents, titletoc, leaders

### Edit

I have rephrased this question and, following a suggestion by one of the answerers here, I have posted it as a new question, [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/668560/how-can-i-achieve-this-formatting-of-the-table-of-contents-toc-using-titletoc).

### The original question

Consider the following table of contents:

[image]

Note that the middle TOC entry is lacking the dotted line. Meanwhile, the first and last entries in the ToC differ just a little bit from the middle one, but those tiny differences are enough to result in the dotted lines being generated normally.

This ToC was generated by the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[paper=letterpaper,left=1.25in,right=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\contentsmargin[140bp]{10pt}
\titlecontents{section}[1in]{}{}{}{\titlerule*[3.3pt]{.}\contentspage}
% the same issue occurs if, instead of the \titlecontents command
% above, we use \dottedcontents{section}[1in]{}{2em}{3.3pt} .
% This is not surprising given that \dottedcontents is defined
% using \titlecontents
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{Verifying a noninterpretable magenta soundness\ }
\section{Verifying a noninterpretable magenta soundness}
\section{Verifying a noninterpretable magenta source}
\end{document}
```

If we tweak some of the length parameters in `\titlecontents` and/or `\contentsmargin`, the dotted line would reappear for the middle entry (but it might disappear for one of the other two!).

But all this hacking is very annoying. First of all, in a long-enough document, it may well happen that you tweak the length parameters to repair a dotted line in one ToC entry, only to find that now the dotted line has disappeared in another entry. Yes, you could, alternatively, leave the length parameters as they are and instead tweak the section titles by rephrasing or adding an extra space at the end. But that is annoying also, as it still requires human intervention.

Is there any way to make the dotted line 'behave' properly? The solution should be compatible with `titletoc`.

Note 1: in my actual document, I am also using `titlesec`. Thus, I should not switch to `toctofl`, as using `toctofl` and `titlesec` together is not recommended.

Note 2: switching to the `memoir` class is not practical, since my actual document has tons of other formatting and customizations that I would have to revisit if I were to make that switch.

### Edit

It might be helpful if I explained what I'm actually trying to achieve. It is this:

[image]

Namely:

1. The names of the sections have a right margin that is much larger than (i.e. it is far to the left from) the right margin of the dots.
2. The dots, however, don't start at the right margin of the names of the sections. Rather, they start wherever each individual section title ends, which will generally be to the left of the right margin of the titles. The dots end at their own right margin, which is much smaller (i.e. it is much further to the right, almost all the way to the page numbers).
3. This effect should be automatically generated, without any need to tweak either the length parameters of `titletoc` or the section titles themselves, no matter (within reason) what the right margin of the titles is, no matter (within reason) what the right margin of the dots is, and no matter (within reason) what the section titles may be.

(For instance, in order to generate this example, I had to tweak the optional argument of `\contentsmargin`; the parameters I eventually used are

```
\contentsmargin[160bp]{15pt}
\dottedcontents{section}[1in]{}{2em}{3.3pt}
```

Originally I had `175bp` instead of `160bp`, and this resulted in the first entry losing its dotted line and its page number being displayed far to the left—the same sort of problem as in the middle entry of my original example.)

Answer (score 1):

`\contentmargin` requires  one mandatory parameter. It is use to allocate space for the page number in the ToC.

Usually it is used to allow boldfaced page numbers with numbers above 100. A sensible choice for this example  would be `\contentsmargin{4ex}`

[image: a2]

```
% !TeX TS-program = pdflatex

\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[paper=letterpaper,left=1.25in,right=1in,showframe]{geometry} % changed to show margins
\usepackage{titletoc}

\contentsmargin{4ex}%  space for page numbers <<<<<<<<<<<
        
\titlecontents{section}[1in]{}{}{}{\,\titlerule*[3.3pt]{.}{\bfseries\contentspage}} % changed: bold page numbers <<<<
    
\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents

    \newpage    
    \section{Verifying a noninterpretable magenta soundness\ }
    \section{Verifying a noninterpretable magenta soundness}        
    
    \newpage\setcounter{page}{100} % added <<<<<<<<<<<<
    \section{Verifying a noninterpretable magenta source}
    %\section{Verifying a noninterpretable magenta source xxx xxx xxx xxx xxx xxx}
\end{document}
```

There is an optional argument in `\contentsmargin`:

```
\contentsmargin[<correction>]{<space>}
```

The (small) correction length is used to deal with special cases where there is a line of text is longer than the last dot, by adding it to the `<space>`.

For example adding

```
\section{Verifying a noninterpretable magenta source xxx xxx xxx xxx xxx xxx}
```

[image: b]

while  using    `\contentsmargin[10pt]{4ex}`

[image: c]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. If I understood it correctly, you are suggesting that the problem with my MWE is that the optional argument of `\contentsmargin` is too large—that I'm employing it to do something it wasn't designed to do. Namely, I'm employing it to make it so that the textual part of the entries in the ToC (i.e. the titles themselves) have a significantly larger right margin than the dots. If I am not supposed to do this using the optional argument of `\contentsmargin`, is there another way I could do it, using `titletoc`?

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. Unfortunately, this is not what I had in mind—I definitely **do not** want to increase the space between the text of the entries and the dots. In order to explain better what it is I **do** want, I have added an **Edit** section to my question, above.

Comment: @linguisticturn I think this is a different question from "TOC entry is lacking the dotted line" or the title of the question. You should ask a new question. This site works better with one question at the time for the benefit of other readers.

Comment: Very well. [Done](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/668560/how-can-i-achieve-this-formatting-of-the-table-of-contents-toc-using-titletoc).

Comment: Not relevant to the answer itself, but to basic (La)TeX -- the `ex` dimension is vertical; `em` is horizontal.